# Why does setInterval only seem to work once in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to play with the setInterval method and I'm just wondering what I have done wrong here. If I program it to return an alert, no problem - it appears at every interval as expected. However, I want my background color to change every few seconds and it's not happening. The color is altered once and that's all the fun I get.

[image]

I've had a look at similar posts on Stack Overflow and played around, but to no avail. Any suggestions much appreciated. Thanks million!

Comment: Please post real code, not an image of the code. You can make it even better: create an SO snippet. Regarding your question, the problem is that the random number is chosen just once, and therefore `choice1` is always the same colour. Move the random selection to inside the `changeColor`.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` function is in fact running every 2 seconds, but `choice1` variable it's being randomized once. You have to generate new values to `choice1` inside `setInverval` callback to get the result you want.
An example:

```js
function changeColor() {
   choice1 = /*Your random function here*/
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = choice1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, Yuri Santos. This has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the setInterval works properly.
The issue is you don't get a new `choice1`.

You can try this

```js
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = oneArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * oneArray.length)]
```